# Como permitir que o meu app seja movido para o cartão de memória?

Tags: android

Todos os aplicativos que estou desenvolvendo de testes não permitem que eu mova-os para o cartão de memoria. Tem como fazer isso? Tem que pedir alguma permissão no `Manifest.xml`?

Coloquei a propriedade que o `android:installLocation` no Manifest.xml e até funcionou, mas estou com o seguinte problema.

Quando eu troco de celular para o Cartão e tento abrir o app da erro, mas se eu reiniciar o celular e abrir o app de novo funciona, dai eu passo para o celular e quando vou abrir o app da erro, mas se eu reiniciar e abrir o app funciona e assim fica.

Eu até consegui trocar de um lugar para outro, mas preciso reiniciar o celular para funcionar o app. Vou colocar aqui um trecho do erro oque está dando:

```
09-21 01:03:46.868  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta W/art? Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /mnt/asec/com.anderson.escuta-1/pkg.apk in OatFile /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.anderson.escuta-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex
09-21 01:03:46.868  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta E/art? oat file /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.anderson.escuta-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex does not contain contents for /mnt/asec/com.anderson.escuta-1/pkg.apk with checksum 786154219
09-21 01:03:46.868  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta E/art? oat file /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.anderson.escuta-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex contains contents for /data/app/com.anderson.escuta-2.apk
09-21 01:03:46.868  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/class_linker.cc:955] Failed to remove obsolete oat file from /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.anderson.escuta-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting...
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Aborting thread:
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x653aa060 self=0x4191cdd8
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21820 nice=-20 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x400a1154
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=R schedstat=( 40233070 20508181 144 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=1 HZ=100
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0xbe526000-0xbe52a000 stackSize=8MB
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x41848214] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x418403a4] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Runtime::Abort()+79 [0x41840934] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+505 [0x416eda7a] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::ClassLinker::FindDexFileInOatFileFromDexLocation(std::string const&, unsigned int)+571 [0x41709dd8] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4181064c] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native method)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:296)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:80)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:59)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:263)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:230)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:112)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:65)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:57)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x60c49c30> (a android.util.ArrayMap)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:329)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x658d5558> (a android.app.LoadedApk)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:518)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4388)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1260)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] All threads:
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] DALVIK THREADS (13):
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Runnable
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x653aa060 self=0x4191cdd8
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21820 nice=-20 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x400a1154
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=R schedstat=( 72628903 34617087 268 ) utm=5 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0xbe526000-0xbe52a000 stackSize=8MB
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x41848214] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::ThreadList::DumpLocked(std::ostream&)+67 [0x41853184] (libart.so)
09-21 01:03:47.128  21820-21820/com.anderson.escuta A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x41840456] (libart.so)
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Anderson, como assim mover? Você diz o usuário mover pelas configurações do sistema?

Comment: Isso mesmo! Eu vi que alguns app permitem isso, mas os que eu  fiz aqui nenhum permite. kkk

Comment: Anderson, qual versão do seu Android? Achei um bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34880 relacionado a essa questão, que é da versão 4.1.1, talvez corrigido na 4.1.2. Parece que tem relatos que ainda persiste na versão 4.4...

Comment: A minha versão é a 4.1.1 mesmo. Mas o estranho que já testei vários app que baixei do playsotre até com versões bem inferiores e nunca tive esse problema. Não sei oque pode ser. ;/ Mas mesmo assim vlw

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser mesmo, tente em outro dispositivo. Não sei nem como ajudar muito, pesquisei bem e não achei nenhum padrão ou alguma solução...

Comment: ok, tudo bem.
Quando eu descobrir eu posto aqui.

Answer (score 5):

Usando a propriedade `android:installLocation` da tag `<manifest>` é possível controlar a local de instalação do aplicativo.

Existem três valores possíveis:

1. `internalOnly`, que é o padrão caso não informe um valor para o atributo. Com ele o aplicativo é instalado na memória interna e não pode ser movido.
2. `preferExternal` define que a instalação deve ser feita preferencialmente no armazenamento externo. O Sistema pode não honrar essa requisição caso não haja nenhum armazenamento externo montado durante a instalação.
3. Com o valor `auto` o sistema instala o aplicativo na memória interna, mas fornece a possibilidade ao usuário de alterar para o armazenamento externo.

Para usar basta setar no seu `AndroidManifest`:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nome.do.seu.pacote"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly|preferExternal|auto">

    ...

</manifest>
```

Referências:

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install

Comment: Funcionou, consegui passar o app para o cartão de memoria, mas quando eu abro ele da vários erros, vou colar algumas linhas aqui:
art/runtime/class_linker.cc:955] Failed to remove obsolete oat file from /data/dalvik-cache/mnt@asec@com.anderson.escuta-1@pkg.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied

Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock

Na verdade o erro é bem grande mas não coube aqui, como devo fazer para reportar o erro nesses casos?

Comment: Estranho, pelo que entendi do erro, tem uma mistura de `dalvik` com `art`, mudou de `runtime` nesse meio tempo? Esse erro aparece naquele `Dialog` padrão do Android? Ou no logcat? Tente voltar o app todo pra memória interna e reinstala pra ver se resolve. Amanhã eu dou uma pesquisada melhor.

Comment: Não mudei nada, só coloquei o "android:installLocation".
Queria te mostrar o Log inteiro do erro, como faço? Pois não cabe aqui. Coloco como resposta da pergunta?

Comment: Coloca na sua pergunta, formatada como código, porque tem altura limitada.